# How to write a Android native linux app to communicate via usb to PC?

Tags: android, usb, usb-drive

I need to do do a boottime sync across devices. So I need to quick and stable way to communicate with Android smart phone.

So far I want to write a Android Linux native app to communicate to PC. Android device is a USB target device, and PC is a host device.

Examples on Google teach you how to write app on USB host, few talks about app on USB target. Is there any example?

Comment: Can you please add links to the examples that "Google teaches"? Because to my knowledge usually USB on Android is used with Android in USB OTG mode, which means it is the host - just the opposite of what you wrote. Also can you please explain what you mean by "boottime sync"? What is the difference to a common time sync?

Comment: In my scenario, it is necessary to establish a correspondence between the timestamps on the device end and those on my PC, with an error margin within 1ms.

And I'm pretty sure Android device can act as target. Think about "adb". It's a PC host communicate to Android USB target

Comment: Yes, adb is an option. Based on your question it wasn't clear if you are trying to develop a sync app for common users (then adb would not have been a good option as most users don't have enabled dev options + adb)  or a special sync software for some special devices you control. If it is the latter, easiest option is adb port forwarding as you don't have to deal with USB itself, just common TCP/UDP.